# Use Two Recycler View List Items Layouts One By One

Tags: android

How to use the two View one by one for a RecyclerView. Here's the code I'm using:

Adapter Code To Fetch The Layout:

```
public tagsfeatures onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout,parent,false);
    return new my_item_layout(view);
}
```

XML For View:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/noti_bg_item"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/tag_features_img"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            ></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tag_features_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="Awesome Title"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/roboto"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tag_features_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="I'm the description text here"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/roboto"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Layout Successfully shows and items are showing in the recycler view. Now I need to display the items differently.

Let's say:

```
//recyclerview
Item0// Image here, Title, Description //Item0
Item1// Title, Description, Image //Item1
Item2// Image here, Title, Description //Item2
Item3// Title, Description, Image //Item3
//recycler view
```

I can create Two layouts for the recycler view items to display the content differently. But currently, I'm not able to use one layout one by one to loop the Items.

Update: I've used the following code but it returns the 2nd layout only:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    final int dataObj = '0';
    if(dataObj == 0 ){
     return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
@Override
public tagsfeatures onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == 0) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.1stlayout, parent, false);
        return new tagsfeatures(view);
    }
    else{
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.2ndlayout, parent, false);
        return new tagsfeatures(view);
    }
}
```

Entire Adapter:

```
package com.example.videoseo.adapters;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.videoseo.R;
import com.example.videoseo.activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.videoseo.activities.theact;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class TagFeaturesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagFeaturesAdapter.tagsfeatures> {
    List<Integer> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> desList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public TagFeaturesAdapter(List<Integer> imageList, List<String> titleList, List<String> desList) {
        this.imageList = imageList;
        this.titleList = titleList;
        this.desList = desList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int thepos = imageList.get(position);
        switch (thepos){
            case 0:
                return 0;
            default:
             return 1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public tagsfeatures onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int postype = viewType;
        switch (postype) {
            case 0:
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tag_features, parent, false);
                return new tagsfeatures(view);
            case 1:
                View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tag_features0, parent, false);
                return new tagsfeatures(view2);
                default:
                    View view3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tag_features, parent, false);
                    return new tagsfeatures(view3);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull tagsfeatures holder, final int position) {
        holder.toolimg.setImageResource(imageList.get(position));
        holder.title.setText(titleList.get(position));
        holder.description.setText(desList.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageList.size();

    }
    public class tagsfeatures extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView toolimg;
        TextView title, description;
        public tagsfeatures(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            toolimg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_features_img);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_features_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_features_desc);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at my [Adapter](https://github.com/kasimoz/Exchange_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/exchangeandroid/adapters/SettingsAdapter.kt)

Comment: I've updated my question, followed your method but still having some issues...

Comment: final int dataObj = '0'; this line always gives you return 0

Comment: I used it for testing,i've used following line: int thepos = imageList.get(position); but still nothing

Comment: I can use position%2 for testing. I think, you should share all the adapter

Comment: I've added the Adapter code, please check

Comment: @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position%2;
}

Comment: Thans, working fine

Comment: Happy coding. You can follow my codes. It helps for you.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

in your recyclerview adapter override getItemViewType function

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            return when(dataList.get(position).type) {
                "typeOne" -> 0;
                "typeTwo" -> 1;
                else -> 2
            }
        }
```

the type returned from this function will be passed to onCreateViewHolder function. Based on the viewType you can load different layout files

Comment: I've updated my question by adding the new code that I've tried. Please check....